# WebPack and Owl-Carousel error Unexpected character

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend, owl-carousel

Webpack config:

https://hastebin.com/ciceyowagu.js

Added to index.js:

```
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css';
import 'owl.carousel';
```

But in Chrome console i got:
[image]

What i have to do?
Thank you!

Comment: Pls show your webpack config. Looks like you didn't handle images with file loader

Comment: @ArtemSky i've added the link (я добавил ссылку)